# wiring ac input to linear DC power supply

Tags: linear-regulator

I have a vintage linear DC power supply. Terminals 1 and 2 are labeled just "AC input". Wanted to double check if there is a convention for which pin is hot, or if the polarity is irrelevant in this case.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

There is no convention. You must treat both wires as being equally dangerous. Both must be kept isolated from your chassis.

Comment: OK thanks, Ill keep that in mind.  But it doesn't matter which is live and which is neutral, correct?

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.